# React child component's state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a parent component, PlanList:

```
class PlanList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderPlans = this.renderPlans.bind(this);
    this.planListFilter = <PlanListFilter onChange={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)} />
  }

  loadPlans() {
    console.log(this.planListFilter);
    // returns: Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: Object, _owner: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper…}

    console.log(this.planListFilter.state);
    // returns: undefined
    // I expect it to return the state object i defined in the PlanListFilter constructor

    // here I would apply the filters to the PlanTable
  }

  handleFilterChange(event) {
    this.loadPlans();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="PlanList">
        {this.planListFilter}
        <PlanTable />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and a child component, PlanListFilter:

```
class PlanListFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: '',
    };
    this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearchChange(event) {
    this.setState({search: event.target.value});
    this.props.onChange(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.handleSearchChange} value={this.state.search} />
    );
  }
}
```

When changing the text on the FormControl, the `onChange` property is fired as expected, but in the parent object, the `state` of the child is `undefined`. I expect it would be populated with the correct state.

Comment: obviously, its not defined in the constructor..

Comment: Yes it is: 

    `constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          search: '',
        };`

Comment: oh, I see, you are doing some crazy shit.. its not how react works..

Comment: Care to enlighten me?

Comment: `this.planListFilter` contains a component descriptor, not an actual instance of a component. And besides, there is no reason to access the state of another component. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I can try, can you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: In addition to the filter, there's a table below (omitted for brevity, but I guess relevant now). It's a pretty basic setup, i'd just like to be able to filter the table. So the parent object needs to access the child's state to know what filters to apply when querying for data to draw the table.

Comment: I'm with @webdeb, you are trying to use React in a very odd way. I'd suggest finding a getting started tutorial that walks you through props and state, declarative concepts and general React principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React data flows in one direction, if your parent should know about changes in the child, you have to pass a handler as a prop to the child, so it will be called from within the child.

```
class Papa extends React.Component {
  constructor(p, c) { super(p, c) }
  handleFilterChange(valueFromChild) {
   //
  }
  render() {
     return <Child filterHandler={this.handleFilterChange} />
  }
}

const Child = ({filterHanlder}) => (
   <button onClick={() => filterHandler('valueToParent') } >Click Me</button>
)
```

Comment: So the short answer is: I was using state wrong. These should be properties and the top-most component should own the state. It should set the properties of child objects based on its state.

Comment: Yeah, you should also take a look at **redux** @Ben174